# Is there a keyword recognition system without learning the Phoneme

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition

As I understand in speech processing and machine learning area "keyword recognition" (also termed as keyword spotting)  is a important part. In "keyword recognition" sytem it is desired to learn a specific word like'yes', 'no', etc. The words can be spoken by anyone so this is not related to speaker recognition.

In all the literature I have read, any keyword recognition system requires to learn the Phonemes of the word and the system needs to find the Phonemes even if they are uttered in different speed by different people.

The question, is there a keyword recognition system whcih does not use Phonemes to learn the system, it learns the whole word itself? Is it possible to do so? If not what is the major problems associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many examples when DNN recognizes the whole word, you can check

[SMALL-FOOTPRINT KEYWORD SPOTTING USING DEEP NEURAL NETWORKS](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/ru//pubs/archive/42537.pdf)

for the open source implementation you can check something like

https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-precise